# How to split a column into different columns in R

Tags: r, split, columnsorting

I have data in which the education column takes the form from 1 to 3.
Payment column - also accepts values from 1 to 3
I wanted to group them in pairs

I have an education and payment column. How can I convert the table so that the payment is divided into 3 different columns
[image]

I would like the table to look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6YFJ.png)

*I tried to do this but it gave me an error [image]

Comment: Please post some reproducible data and give us a clearer idea of what exactly you are looking for

Comment: Have a look at `tidyr::pivot_wider`, e.g. try `DATA %>% tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Education, values_from = count, names_prefix = "Education = ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `pivot_wider` from the `tidyr` package is the way to go:

```
library(dplyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Education,
               values_from = count,
               names_glue = "Education = {.name}")
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  PaymentTier `Education = 1` `Education = 2` `Education = 3`
        <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
1           1            1000             666            6543
2           2              33            2222            9999
3           3             455            1111            5234
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Education = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  PaymentTier = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
  count = c(1000,33,455,666,2222,1111,6543,9999,5234)
)
```